# When is a trigger fired?

Tags: sql-server, trigger

My portal will be picking data every 2 hours from a file to a SQL Server table, lets say `TableSource`. As data is received in `TableSource`, it should also be copied into `TableDestination`, so we wrote a trigger for it.

My question is: what is the interval or rate of triggers getting fired in SQL Server? Will it be fired for each row (like MySQL), or after 500 inserts or after completion of all the inserts?

Data will be inserted in bulk, not manual entries.. maybe like 40k - 50k per hour. Can I run my trigger only once, after all my 40K are completely inserted into `TableSource`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Controlling Trigger Execution When Bulk Importing Data](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187640(v=sql.105).aspx)

> A *trigger* is a special form of stored procedure that is executed automatically when a user modifies data in a table or view.
>
> [...]
>
> If triggers are enabled, they are executed once for each batch.

You can also track the behavior of the triggers. So you can make triggers to be executed only once per bulk import operation.

Another solution is to create a stored procedure, which will do exactly the same things that you are doing inside your triggers. You can call that SP after the bulk import operation completes in the same transaction.

---

[`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) is a T-SQL command. Whenever you write a bulk insert you can specify the `BATCHSIZE` parameter:

> `BATCHSIZE` = *batch_size*
> Specifies the number of rows in a batch. Each batch is copied to the server as one transaction. If this fails, SQL Server commits or rolls back the transaction for every batch. By default, all data in the specified data file is one batch.

Answer (score 4):

On a `FOR/AFTER` type trigger, it gets fired immediately after each insert, update or delete statement, prior to commit.

An `INSTEAD OF` trigger works differently and actually provides alternate logic for your insert, update or delete.  It fires in place of your insert, update or delete statement.  In this case it doesn't sound like the right approach.

Use the *inserted* or *deleted* logical tables to capture the results of the insert or delete. Since you are doing bulk inserts, make sure to write the trigger to handle multiple rows at a time.

I'm not a big fan of the approach but I've seen a lot of developers using cursors in triggers. That tends to have negative performance impacts so I usually stick to normal insert statements.

One additional point, though, which I should clarify: if you are actually using the T-SQL [`BULK INSERT` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql), it's possible that triggers will be skipped. There is an override, `FIRE_TRIGGERS` that you will want to make sure to use. From that documentation link:

> `FIRE_TRIGGERS`
>   Specifies that any insert triggers defined on the destination table execute during the bulk-import operation. If triggers are defined for `INSERT` operations on the target table, they are fired for every completed batch.
>
> If `FIRE_TRIGGERS` is not specified, no insert triggers execute.